# Xcode 10 build fails with 'Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10, swiftmessages

I updated Xcode to version 10 recently and started to receive a strange error when trying to build my project. I'm currently on Swift 4.0 and I did try to upgrade to swift Version 4.2. But when I did I received this same error in many of my frameworks.

> Command Compile Swift failed with a nonzero exit code

So far I've deleted the derived folder. Updated all pods, also deleted all pods and reinstalled them using the terminal commands below.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
pod deintegrate
pod clean
pod install
```

This didn't work to fix my issue. However, I found something that could work which was adding `arm64` architecture in `Build Setting -> valid architectures` and enabling automatic code But, when I checked it was already there and code signing was enabled already.

Additionally, I do have a few other build errors that have to do with frameworks.

**SwiftMessages**

> Value of type 'SwiftMessages.Config' has no member 'presentationContext'

**WhatsNewKit**

> Missing argument for parameter 'backgroundColor' in call`

I opened issues with the developers of each of these frameworks to seek help with these issues.

[Issue On SwiftMessage GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages/issues/229)
[Issue On WhatsNewKit GitHub](https://github.com/SvenTiigi/WhatsNewKit/issues/5)

When I click `presentationContext` it brings me to the struct within the `SwiftMessages` Framework. Usually, when I've had the "has no member" warning I cannot click to see the original place where it exists.

I assume this has something to do with cocoa pods, but haven't been able to find a solution yet. What can I do to correct this issue? If anyone could help would be deeply appreciated been stuck on this for a day now.

Update:
The two frameworks latest builds were for swift 4.2. When I changed the version of each framework to one that was built in swift 4.0 I got the project to build.

Comment: I have the same problem its happened after I update to Xcode10 and try to pod update.

Comment: I've come across the same thing (or something very similar). Try cleaning your workspace (Cmd+Shift+K), then do a `pod deintegrate` followed by a `pod install`. You could also try to delete your derived data folder (usually `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`).

Comment: Try this answer in a similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52499525/751641

Comment: Try this answer in a similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52499525/751641

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build fails with "Command failed with a nonzero exit code"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690619/build-fails-with-command-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

Comment: I know that you already tried restarting and rebuilding everything, the only working solution is - Reinstall the Xcode!!!!

Comment: @AlejandroIván For some reason I don't see the Xcode folder. Is there a setting in macOS that keeps certain files hidden in Finder, or did my Xcode folder get installed in a different place?

Comment: The `Library` folder is hidden by default in the Finder. You can press `Cmd+Shift+.` (command shift dot) to show/hide hidden files.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that, your project Swift Language Version is in the proper version. SwiftMessages 6.0.0 works with Swift 4.2.
[image: Xcode->Project->Target->Build Settings->Swift Language Version]

Comment: Somehow my frameworks ended up having difference Swift versions. So, making sure they were all the same solved my issue. In my case, I wanted them all to be Swift 4.2. Remember Xcode's Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax to help in the Migration and always double that the Swift version under Build Settings got changed accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this way:

1. Comment all pods in your **.pod** file
2. From your terminal, run the command **pod install --no-repo-update**
3. Open Xcode perform a **clean and rebuild the project**
4. Now open your **.pod** file and uncomment the first library
5. From your terminal, run the command **pod install**

Repeat steps **2 - 3 - 4 -5** for each uncomment library in your **.pod** file

I hope it can be of your help.

Comment: this method just saved me from going c###€!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that, Your project build settings **Optimization Level** is in **No Optimization[-Onone].**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

for pod SwiftMessages if your app is not swift 4.2 you need to user the version 5.01
pod 'SwiftMessages', '~> 5.0.1'

and it will work like a charm

Answer (score 4):

Set Swift version to 4.2 then pod deintegrate, pod install, fix this problem for me. Thanks @alejandro-iván

Answer (score 4):

Good Morning!
Do a clean. using"**commond + shift + k**
Close Xcode.
Navigate to project directory where the Podfile exist.
Do pod update/pod install
Open x.xcworkspace

Answer (score 4):

[image]

This error happened to me when I used same class name in two different groups. Then I renamed one of the classes and the problem was solved

Answer (score 3):

I had several frameworks (homegrown) plus my app. Somehow they ended up being out of sync as far as the Swift version. Make sure that all frameworks are the same version. In my case, they all needed to be set to Swift 4.2. If you haven't done the migration to 4.2 then remember that Xcode helps with this: Edit -> Convert -> To Current Swift Syntax.

Answer (score 3):

All of the answers were helpful to me. In my case, I only install frameworks manually but this kind of problem also happens. I tried all of the answers and was still getting this issue during the build. Curiously, while coding, I could cmd-click and resolve all of the "missing" components. I also cleaned and deleted derived data, restarted Xcode, etc.

I eventually got it working by inducing these additional steps:

On **each** of the framework project/targets (including my own):

- Verify consistent Swift version (4.2 in my case)
- Set Build for Active Architecture Only to **No**
- Set Valid Architecture to **arm64, armv7** (to match with base project)
- Set Optimization Level to **None** (for Debug)
- Set Compilation Mode to **Whole**

Answer (score 3):

only for **re-install** pod using that command **`pod install`**
see below attachment

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case I connect an actual iphone not simulator and run the app once on it, It solved the problem. But connect iphone firstly, then choose it from this menu, then press run button.
The problem will solve too.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this problem when upgrading to Xcode 10.2 and Swift 5. After trying everything I found this in the release notes:

> The Swift compiler may crash during a build when the Thread Sanitizer
>   is enabled. (48719789)

And sure enough, efter turning off Thread Sanitizer my project could be compiled without errors again.

So if you get this error and have Thread Sanitizer enabled - turn it off!

Answer (score 1):

Same issue happened to me in Xcode 10.2, it was a Xcode bug..!
So, I opened in older Xcode version(9.4), and it worked fine. Then I updated to the Xcode 10.2.1 after it's release -> Clean and build your project, now my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem, my Xcode version is 10.2.1 (10E1001),
Cocoapods version is 1.7.0.beta.2.

I returned to Cocoapods 1.6.1 and the problem was solved.
The specific steps are:

1. `pod deintegrate` to cancel the integration.
2. Uninstall all Cocoapods.

   ```
   for i in $( gem list --local --no-version | grep cocoapods );
   do
       gem uninstall $i;
   done
   ```
3. Install the stable version of Cocoapods. For now it's 1.6.1.

   ```
   gem install cocoapods
   ```
4. Clean Project and empty DerivedData⁩
5. `pod install`
6. Recompile the project

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a code error:

```
self.myDto.map{ (dto)} in 
      var stringValue = (dto.value(forKey: "name") as! String)
      stringValue.append("c")
      return stringValue
}
```

Just removed that `stringValue` variable fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error message and none of the answers here and in the duplicates of this question were applicable to my project or helpful.
I kept on reading through the error messages and came to a realisation that I had stupidly named two seperate swift files in different folders with the same name intending to change one, but before I got to change one, I tried to run my project and have been annoyed for the last hour.

Bottom line, don't accidentally name your files the same name and read your error codes thoroughly!

Answer (score 0):

```
target 'XYZ' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for xyz
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'Localize-Swift'
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'Kingfisher'
    pod 'Tabman'
    pod 'RSSelectionMenu'
    pod 'Pushbots'
    pod 'ACProgressHUD-Swift', '~> 1.4' 
    pod 'SKPhotoBrowser'
    pod 'ZoomableImageSlider'
    pod 'RSSelectionMenu'
    pod 'DropDown'
    pod 'ImagePicker'

end
```

I updated platform :ios, '10.0' to 11.0 and the error disappeared. Change your platform or OS version and check. Hope that could help.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your pod's version for example  `pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 5.3.5'`
or uncomment `# platform :ios, '9.0'` in your Podfile

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on Xcode 14. Add this on podfile bottom.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    # some older pods don't support some architectures, anything over iOS 11 resolves that
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
    end
  end
end
```