# Xcode Application Not Working / Won't Build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

[image]

Hello,
I recently updated Xcode to 11.0 and then to 11.1. During my coding while using my iPhone on IOS 13.1.2 I noticed an error "Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code". This error appears anytime I change anything in my code and try to build again. It takes forever to build and basically makes coding impossible. It also says "Building From Memory" somethings when trying to build. I noticed that this Command CompileSwift error also appears on a default "Hello World" SpriteKit Game without me editing anything. Things I have done to try and fix this error:

1) Import the code of my game into a new project.

2) Create a new project (Game) "Hello World" without editing any code to see if the error is still there (it is)

3) Trying to build to an iPad instead of iPhone

4) Trying to build onto a lower IOS version 11.4 instead of IOS 13.1.2

5) Deleting Xcode and downloading Xcode 10.3, creating a new project (Game)"Hello World" without editing any code and trying to build onto IOS 11.4

6) Trying to build onto an iPhone simulator

7) Looking online at similar people who had this error. Most of those who had this error had been using cocoa pods (which I have installed before but not using atm) or had found errors in their coding.

Note: When looking in the error log, it shows nothing apart from the picture provided. It doesn't show which line the error is coming from, or which part. Even with the default "Hello World" project there is no indication of where the error is coming from or what is causing it.

Nothing I tried above worked. I could understand if this error appeared due to my coding, but I don't understand how this error still appears even when I download Xcode 10.3, open a brand new project (Game) and try to build the default "Hello World" onto IOS 11.4?

I first noticed this error updating to Xcode 11. Before that I don't remember seeing this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This error basically makes coding impossible.

Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 10 build fails with 'Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52415877/xcode-10-build-fails-with-command-compileswift-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

Comment: Thanks. Checking the link you sent!

Comment: I tried everything in that link. Nothing worked. If I clean the project and try to build, it will build but takes 260 seconds (4 minutes) to build. Most of the time is used in "Compile Swift Source Files". Once it builds, if I change ANY code and try to build again, I get the "Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code" again, and have to clean the project to remove that error and try to build again (another 4 minutes)

Comment: Update. I completely deleted my hard-drive, and re-installed macOS from scratch. I'm still getting the error "Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code". Could it be something with my signing and capabilities?