# error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xcode12, xcframework

I have switched to `Xcode12` for one of my static library apps. I am trying to make XCFramework distribution. After running build command,

```
xcodebuild archive -scheme "MySDK" -sdk iphoneos  -archivePath “./archives/ios.xcarchive” -SKIP_INSTALL=NO
```

I am getting below error when I switched `Build Settings -> Build Libraries for Distribution` to `YES`,

```
<unknown>:0: error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwiftSources normal armv7 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwiftSources normal armv7s com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(3 failures)
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60658142/1084174) works but unfortunately creating `.xcframework` requires to set the option distribution `YES`.

**How to resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple seems to be deprecating bridging headers in favor of modules, but [their documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis) regarding *how* to include C headers is missing. The information is instead found in the more detailed [clang docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html).

Try removing the bridging header from the project settings and instead create a `module.modulemap` file:

```
module MySdk {
   header "MySdk-Bridging-Header.h"
   export *
}
```

This has caveats, such as needing to `import MySdk` in your swift code and understanding that C functions will be exposed, but it got me over the hump.

One trick I discovered by trial and error is to include this modulemap file and C headers in the framework's `Headers` folder. This allows any app consuming the framework to automatically detect `MySdk` as a module.