# Flutter using jitsi_meet flutter package generate error on IOS

Tags: flutter, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am attempting to create a flutter app and integrate the jitsi_meet flutter package i followed the instructions indicated on documentation.

My flutter version and IOS via flutter doctor

```
Flutter version 2.8.1
develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.1)
```

My configuration pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  jitsi_meet: ^4.0.0
```

My Podfile

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Added below keys/string on my pslist

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) MyApp needs access to your camera for meetings.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) MyApp needs access to your microphone for meetings.</string>
```

After this configuration i also change the deployment build to ios 11 as stated from other solutions but after running build using my `simulator iPhone 13` below error occur

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    <module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
    #import "Headers/jitsi_meet-umbrella.h"
            ^
    /Users/kaori/Documents/development/projects/fluttermeet/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/jitsi_meet/jitsi_meet-umbrella.h:13:9: note: in file included from /Users/kaori/Documents/development/projects/fluttermeet/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/jitsi_meet/jitsi_meet-umbrella.h:13:
    #import "JitsiMeetPlugin.h"
            ^
```

Cannot get it to build on ios.

Comment: use pod install in flutter . then run in xcode

Comment: HI any luck with this, facing same issue

Comment: @Tasnuvaoshin yeah i did that also same error on Xcode

Comment: @shubhamsachan no luck as of now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it to build by adding below lines on my podfile

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

....


post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
        # Required by jitsi
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
          config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
     end
  end
end
```

and run `flutter clean` + `flutter pub get` and `cd ios` and run `pod install` now you will encounter a new problem `Xcode 11.2.1 error: Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code` so i followed the solution from this question [Xcode 11.2.1 error: Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59192371/xcode-11-2-1-error-command-compileswiftsources-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

After opening ios folder on Xcode and change the `Build Options` -> `Build Libraries` for `Distribution in the targets Build Settings to No`. And then run `flutter run` inside ios folder and the build was successful, hope this help anyone who encounter the same issue.