# Cannot find type 'PiPViewCoordinator' in scope

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, dart

I am getting following error when i install JitsiMeetSDK in flutter but i am unable to run app. Can somebody suggest me how can i resolve this issue?

[image: error]

I am using following:

- Xcode : 13.1
- Swift : 5
- jitsi_meet: ^4.0.0
- Android Studio Bumblebee

Comment: able to fix it?

Comment: Hello @Iducool, Not yet.

Comment: here is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70604813/flutter-using-jitsi-meet-flutter-package-generate-error-on-ios mostly same as below mentioned but with some additional detail.

Comment: Okay......Will check it. Thank you @Iducool.

Answer (score 4):

Note: Example compilable with XCode 12.2

then -->

Add this line in Podfile

```
post_install do |installer| 

installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
       end
   end
 end
```

Comment: Hello @PesaCoder, thank your for your reply but this solution didn't worked for me.

Comment: platform :ios, '11.0' ???

Comment: platform: ios 12.0

Comment: try run app using XCode

Comment: and try to run 

flutter clean; rm ios/Podfile ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock; rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace; flutter run

Comment: did this but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same problem. I tried building the application on iOS Simulator and it keeps getting swift compile errors of all sorts. I followed Usama solution above and it worked for me.

I'm using

- MacBook M1
- Xcode 14.2
- Flutter 3.7.1
- Android Studio 2022.1 Electric Eel