# Flutter 2.10.3 ios pod file differentiate

Tags: ios, flutter, podfile

I have this code in ios/podfile    with flutter sdk 2.5
`post_install do |installer|`
`installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|`
`target.build_configurations.each do |config|`
`config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'`
`config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'`
`end` `end` `end`

but when upgrade flutter to 2.10.3  this code cant work
there is some changes that do not understand for me

like this

```
post_install do |installer| installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target) end end
```

and I want to add tow next lines in  new style of code

`config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'`
`config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'`

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Hi  bro   I was edit  my question 
maybe now more clear than first

Answer (score 0):

This is code that work for me after more searching

```
post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
        # Required by jitsi
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
          config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
     end
  end
end
```

I got it from here
[Flutter using jitsi_meet flutter package generate error on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70604813/flutter-using-jitsi-meet-flutter-package-generate-error-on-ios)