# React Native: RenderItem in FlatList. How to map array stored in local state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a small application with React Native that has a local SQLite database for storing images but having trouble rendering my array of images (fetched from the local database and stored in the local state).

Before I was rendered by mapping the data and that worked fine.

```
  state = {
    items:[when the user uses the app this array fills with images],
  };
```

```
<ScrollView>
        {items.map(({ id, value }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.deletePhoto}
            key={id}>
            <Image source={{ uri: value }} style={{ width: null, height: 400 }} />
          </TouchableOpacity>

        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

But now I would like to go a step further and render the data in a FlatList with my choice of formatting (a grid). Although I can get the FlatList to render the number of images within the array, I can't get the actual image to show. **I'm not sure how to pass the data successfully?**

```
  renderItem = ({ id, value }) => {
  const { items } = this.state;
  if (items.empty === true) {
    return <View style={[styles.item, styles.itemInvisible]} />;
  }
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={this.deletePhoto} key={id}>
            <Image source={{ uri: value }} style={{ width: null, height: 400 }} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
  };
```

For context, this is the creation of the 'items' SQL Table with the 'id' and 'value' attributes:

```
componentDidMount() {
    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'create table if not exists items (id integer primary key not null, value text);'
      );
    });
  }
```

I guess the question is, how do I pass/access the attributes of the items array into a functional component?

**Update:**

https://ibb.co/hMY1qBy (What I'm getting - e.g DB Entry creating a View but no image rendering)
https://ibb.co/RN4rqyK (What I'm getting from the answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting a reproducible code from your repo that you shared I manage to render the images in the list.

[image: After rendering images in the list]

Here is your `renderItem` function

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  const { items } = this.state;
  if (items.empty === true) {
    return <View style={[styles.item, styles.itemInvisible]} />;
  }
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={this.deletePhoto} key={item.id}>
            <Image source={{ uri: item.value }} style={{ width: 400, height: 120 }} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
  };
```

You have to get the `item` from your params of the `renderItem` function as well you have to pass width to image for rendering, The above code is working fine.

Comment: Great! I understand the logic. How does the FlatList look? As I'm still not getting a rendering of the image - so I assume missing something there.

Comment: I have shown you the code and the list above, If still not work then I can push the code in your repo in a separate branch.

Comment: Got em' - Thank you Waheed.

Comment: Yes, it works almost completely, it just isn't rendering the empty blocks (the top part of the ```renderItem``` function. So figuring that out

Comment: try it, and if not work let me know, I will also render the empty blocks too.

Comment: Understand how to fix it (I believe) but struggling to declare the length of the items array so that the function knows how many empty blocks to render! Essentially the same problem as before (passing through the value of each item) but before you solved it by passing through item as a param with renderItem. Would be fantastic to solve it

Comment: I didn't get you, as my understanding you want to render empty block but what is the use case to render the empty block?

Comment: Because in the FlatList we're looking to render 3 images in each row, or to have 3 columns. So the problem is that when you have a number of posts that are not a multiple of three, eg. 7. The 7th post takes up a full row and 100% width of the screen. I can kind of fix this by formatting the containing view or image to be one third of the screen (which I have done) but then the image places itself awkwardly. By rendering empty blocks, we can make sure each post only takes up a third of the screen and will be placed underneath a column

Comment: https://www.bootdey.com/files/ReactNative/154592422414559588_5c24ee802ad8a.png - is a good example

Comment: Now i got it, Will you please share some example array which you are passing to your list.

Comment: It's exactly the same array/repo you used before actually. There's a ```formatItems``` function that takes all the same arguments and should output the right number of empty blocks to be rendered by ```renderItem```. I'm now calling that function in ```async componentDidMount()``` and trying to figure out how to push the correct amount of empty blocks to the ```items``` array to be rendered

Comment: @JamesStirrat Okay, I will look into this by tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks Waheed - much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The flatlist renderItem prop gets a argument with multiple properties the main ones will be item and index which are commonly used to access the item in of the row you can use item like below

```
<FlatList
        data={items}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={this.deletePhoto} key={item.id}>
            <Image source={{ uri: item.value }} style={{ width: null, height: 400 }} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working. throwing 'undefined is not an object' error for the item.id and item.value. Not sure why I can't access those properties through dot notation yet can pass them through the map method.

Comment: Back to rendering without an image.. I'll update my question to upload a screenshot.

Comment: It seems that the problem is that dot notation doesn't call the attribute yet when the array (items) is called with the map method, we can call properties by passing in the attributes as params. Strange

Comment: I've missed the empty part of your code, better try with that

Comment: @JamesStirrat Can you make a snack on the expo, I can fix it for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I can. It was made with vanilla react native and uses 'react-native-sqlite-storage' so it won't work on expo?

Comment: https://github.com/jamiestirrat/SQLiteStorageReactNative - the repo if that is useful @WaheedAkhtar

Comment: @JamesStirrat In which file the code is, That making problem?

Comment: pages/VaultScreen.js @WaheedAkhtar

Comment: @JamesStirrat getting build issue.
`Command CompileC failed with a nonzero exit code`

Comment: Strange, it seems to be an XCode compile error. I built with the newest version of XCode 11+. Maybe try this to solve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387452/command-compileswift-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-in-xcode-10

Comment: @JamesStirrat above issue is fixed, Your list is empty of vault because data length is zero how can I add data to it?

Comment: Or can you give me JSON response after fetching from DB?

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar You can add data through the 'Add Photo' Button on the initial home screen. Once you choose photo and hit submit it will be added to the DB and will fetch for FlatList

Comment: @JamesStirrat can you do a console log of your state.items and put it here ?