# AN unknown error in xcode when archieving the project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

An unknown error in Xcode appears when achieving the project.

The last thing I do was installing this library using pods: https://github.com/xornorik/SVPinView

When I uninstall this lib everything works fine.

I tried to remove DerivedData and restarting Xcode but the problem still exists.

[Xcode error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQh8P.png)

Comment: Can you share with us the error message?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Have you used ? pod 'SVPinView', '~> 1.0'

Comment: Try to see this existing thread, hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387452/command-compileswift-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-in-xcode-10

Comment: @VinayakaSY  Yes

Comment: @ValMoratalla I tried all the solutions in this thread but nothing works.

Comment: @rs7 https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQh8P.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all guys I solved the problem by creating a new project and moved all files to it.