# xcodebuild build command fails in Xcode 11.5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodebuild, xcode-build-settings

when  build  the app in xcode 11.5  generate this issue. 
**LOG:**  **I hope can help me!! Regards!!**

warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: Cannot Load File: Failed to open diagnostics file (in target 'B7_MOCHA' from project 'B7_MOCHA')

warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: Cannot Load File: Failed to open diagnostics file (in target 'B7_MOCHA' from project 'B7_MOCHA')

warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: Cannot Load File: Failed to open 
diagnostics file (in target 'B7_MOCHA' from project 'B7_MOCHA')

:0: error: unable to execute command: Killed: 9
:0: error: compile command failed due to signal 9 (use -v to see invocation)
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

this a picture from console log:

[image: io]

**the other console show this issue**

/Users/dverdugo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B7_MOCHA-asiprqvqhlstshfnhycalolsjhxs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/B7_MOCHA.build/Debug-iphoneos/B7_MOCHA.build/Objects-normal-asan/arm64/TAG_CHAT.dia:1:1: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: Cannot Load File: Failed to open diagnostics file

[image]

I hope can help me!! Regards!!

Comment: Have you tried clearing your derived data folder? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/can-i-safely-delete-contents-of-xcode-derived-data-folder

Comment: @rs7 I did that but the error persists, I delele all file from the folder developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: @matt  sorry I change this! regards!!

Comment: @rs7 I have little space left on the hard drive, can it be?

Comment: I'm not sure. Have you looked at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387452/command-compileswift-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-in-xcode-10

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the best thing you need to do is
-Close xcode.
-Restar the Mac
-check if the pods you are using installed well.

and for the second error, maybe you deleted some file in the folder of your project so xcode is looking for it and can't find it.

Comment: I solved the problem!! I have two problems!! I need more space in the disc  when build I have only 5 gb the space in the disk minimum  I need 10 gb and more and  change the project in other  new project... because mi project use many pods