# Build failed with "CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After I update swift version to 4.2, I got this error everytime I build for running.

```
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
```

The logcat is as follow:

> CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target: twidere)
>       cd /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere
>       export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
>       export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.0.sdk
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name twidere -Onone -enable-batch-mode -enforce-exclusivity=checked -DDEBUG -D COCOAPODS -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.0.sdk -target x86_64-apple-ios12.0-simulator -g -module-cache-path /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options -enable-testing -index-store-path /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Index/DataStore -swift-version 4.2 -I /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AutoInsetter -F /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NewPopMenu -F /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pageboy -F /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReSwift -F /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReSwiftRouter -F /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Realm -F /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmSwift -F /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RxCocoa -F /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RxSwift -F /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SnapKit -F /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Swinject -F /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Tabman -c -j4 /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Common/SwiftyPlistManager.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Feed/DisplayViewController.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Common/widgets/GMStepper.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Feed/widgets/ScreenNameLabel.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Twidere/AppDelegate.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Feed/FontSizeCell.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Settings/Theming/ThemeViewController.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Common/ext/UITableView+Ext.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Feed/StaticFeedCell.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Settings/SettingsNavViewController.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Common/widgets/KaedeTextField.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Reducers/AppReducer.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Reducers/SettingsReducer.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Feed/FontNameViewController.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Source/SourceEdit+Ext.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Feed/widgets/AvatarImageView.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Common/widgets/TextFieldEffects.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Common/ext/Color+Ext.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Routes/UINavigationController+Ext.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/State/State.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Settings/Ohters/Language+Ext.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Common/widgets/SwitchMenuCell.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Settings/Theming/AppTheme.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Common/widgets/SnapchatCheckbox.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Common/IconFont+Ext.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Common/Enum+Ext.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Source/SourceViewController.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Twidere/Dimension.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Routes/Routes.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Source/Source.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Settings/Ohters/OthersViewController.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Settings/TabItemsProvider.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Settings/Theming/ThemeCell.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Source/EditSourceController.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Feed/widgets/IdLabel.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Source/SourceCell.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Feed/widgets/ContentTextView.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Twidere/NewPopMenu+Ext.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Common/font/Font+Ext.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/State/SettingsState.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Common/font/ScaledFont.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Feed/SelectedFontCell.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Common/String+Ext.swift /Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere/Settings/SettingsTabViewController.swift -output-file-map /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Twidere.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/twidere.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/twidere-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Twidere.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/twidere.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/twidere.swiftmodule -Xcc -I/Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Twidere.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/twidere.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Twidere.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/twidere.build/twidere-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Twidere.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/twidere.build/twidere-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Twidere.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/twidere.build/twidere-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Twidere.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/twidere.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Twidere.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/twidere.build/twidere-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Twidere.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/twidere.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Twidere.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/twidere.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/sinyuk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Twidere-fltbmfgkcodqsfgdhkqzwkuvxyul/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Twidere.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/twidere.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/twidere-Swift.h -Xcc -working-directory/Users/sinyuk/repo/twidere

It licks me how to settle the problem, any advice will be appreciated!

PS: destination: iPhone X | SDK Simulator - iOS 12.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code Xcode 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350896/command-compileswiftsources-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-xcode-10)