# Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am using Xcode 10 and no CocoaPods.

```
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOS_Belt_-_MyEvents-eektunqbfhmzjabcmfpiscjsxlyf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/iOS Belt - MyEvents.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iOS Belt - MyEvents.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/iOS_Belt___MyEvents/iOS_Belt___MyEvents+CoreDataModel.swift'
```

Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: Delete your DerivedData folder and try again?  That often fixes this kind of problem.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52481653/1485367

Comment: Thanks for reaching out Yaroslav! I did try your remedy prior and it didn't work. Apparently what might've fixed it for me was not naming/starting my project name with a "-" or dash character. Rebuilt a new project and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

My instructor was able to help remedy this with me. Apparently, you should avoid having dash (-) characters when naming your project at the start. So just open a new Xcode project and avoid using hyphens in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error when I compile with `Deployment Target` 11.0.

My solution is to change the value to 11.4.